# Compare a "temp' table with values in CTE, then update two different tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a "temp' table populated from an enrollment transportable in java. What I am doing is comparing the "temp" table with values I am populating in a CTE with a select query. What I need to do next is update two different tables. Here is my query for the comparison of the "temp" table and CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
     SELECT S.SYS_USER_NAME, PG.PAX_ID 
     FROM component.SYS_USER S
     INNER JOIN component.PAX_GROUP PG
     ON S.PAX_ID = PG.PAX_ID
     WHERE (ROLE_CODE = 'AC' and THRU_DATE is null) or
     (ROLE_CODE = 'DLRP' and THRU_DATE is null)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
INNER JOIN component.TEMP_CONTROL_NUM
ON TEMP_CONTROL_NUM.CONTROL_NUM = CTE.SYS_USER_NAME
```

What I want to do next is update two different tables. One I need to set a status column as inactive and the other I need to set a thru date.

The issue I am having is writing an UPDATE with a SELECT. I have something like:

```
UPDATE component.SYS_USER SET STATUS = 'I'
    WHERE SYS_USER_NAME =
    (SELECT * FROM CTE INNER JOIN component.TEMP_CONTROL_NUM ON
    TEMP_CONTROL_NUM = CTE.SYS_USER_NAME)
```

Would this be correct? I realize I am only attempting to update one table but I figure if I have one table updating, I can figure out the other. It doesn't seem to be.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: So is it mySql or Sql-Server? Can't be both....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  ...
)
UPDATE u SET
  STATUS = 'I'
FROM component.SYS_USER u
INNER JOIN CTE c on c.SYS_USER_NAME = u.SYS_USER_NAME
INNER JOIN component.TEMP_CONTROL_NUM t ON t.TEMP_CONTROL_NUM = c.SYS_USER_NAME
```